# Nextjs - How to pass params to server router with Link

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Link DOM such as `<Link href="/blog/0", as="/blog/ss" />`
My server router is like this.

```
router.get('/blog/:articleId', async (ctx) => {
  await app.render(ctx.req, ctx.res, '/articles', { articleId: ctx.params.articleId });
  ctx.respond = false;
});
```

How could I get the Link's href value? The `ctx.params.articleId` which I get is `ss`.

**Update:**
the request object

```
{ request:
   { method: 'GET',
     url: '/articles/test-context-1',
     header:
      { host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        dnt: '1',
        'save-data': 'on',
        'user-agent':
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
    accept:
     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    referer: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' } },
  response: { status: 200, message: 'OK', header: {} },
  app: { subdomainOffset: 2, proxy: false, env: 'development' },
  originalUrl: '/articles/test-context-1',
  req: '<original node req>',
  res: '<original node res>',
  socket: '<original node socket>' }
```

Comment: Can you paste request object here. I think you can get it from request object.

Comment: @SaurabhGhewari I update the request object

Comment: Have you tried req.params.articleId instead?

Comment: You should take a look at the `next-routes` package, which did the work for me

Answer (score 1):

It should be ctx.**req.**params.articleId.

You missed `req` in your object.

```
router.get('/blog/:articleId', async (ctx) => {
  await app.render(ctx.req, ctx.res, '/articles', { articleId: ctx.req.params.articleId });
  ctx.respond = false;
});
```